# line-through / strike-through styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website where there is a services page with a few items priced accordingly.

[image: price]

As the site is a responsive layout and the text changes depending on the device it is being viewed on...I'm looking for a way to create the above example in HTML, CSS, JavaScript or something similar without resorting to using an image such as a jpg, png etc.

I'm finding it difficult to create this as there is a line-through on the angle like so, it's a different color and controlling its thickness/weight..The best I can get is a thin line with its parent color, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible with css3 transforms, of course no IE support, but you can use a png as fallback for old browsers:

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ejoguw/1/edit

```
span { position: relative; }
span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px; /* height/2 */
    width: 100%;
    height: 7px; /* Adjust */
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
}
```

Comment: How do you specify this fallback? How would a fallback like this one work?

Comment: Great minds think alike. Just coded this method up as a response myself, using border-bottom instead of height and background-color. As mentioned, support for IE8 and below isn't there. Could fallback to a simple strike through for those browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/wEXWn/

Comment: Yeah simple strike-through would be the simplest fallback, I wouldn't spend much time with images for such a trivial effect.

Comment: you my friend, just won the internet.  thanks for all the input guys.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your strikethrough price in `<s>`, then use JS to hoist an absolutely-positioned PNG on top of all your `<s>` tags (and, obviously, turn off the native strikethrough style). If the PNG has something like `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` then it'll scale accordingly, and shouldn't look too bad. Users without JS will see, semantically, the same thing.

Comment: thank you for the quick response ben, really appreciate the help